# LEFT JOIN with right table criteria

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I would like to join table A and B with the following criteria to get the result table.

TABLE A is the Starting TIME
TABLE B consist of both TIME IN and TIME OUT
USER need to clock in (TIME IN), start machine (TIME START), clock out (TIME OUT)

1. TIME IN >= TIME START
2. TIME START >= TIME OUT
3. MAX TIME IN/OUT
4. DISTINCT Results based on ID

I tried left join but couldn't get the result that I want. I tried using CASE but the are lots of redundant result. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Please translate the information in the image to the question. Could you also include some sample queries you have tried, sample data and the desired results.

Comment: "IN/OUT could be either IN or OUT not necessary IN" -- Not according to the question: IN/OUT is treated as IN. Please elaborate on it, to provide an answer.

Comment: IN/OUT is treated as IN because its less than start time. If its more, it should be out

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID     as id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE
                        WHEN b.Code = 'In'
                            THEN b.Time
           end) as `Time In`,
       `TIME START`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE
                        WHEN b.Code = 'Out'
                            THEN b.Time
           end) as `Time Out`
FROM `Table A` a
JOIN `Table B` b on a.ID = b.ID
WHERE 1
  AND ((b.Code = 'In' && b.`TIME` <= a.`TIME START`) OR
       (b.Code = 'Out' && b.`TIME` >= a.`TIME START`))
GROUP BY a.ID, a.`Time Start`
```

query doesn`t handle Code='In/Out' you need to split this explict

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a couple of `LEFT JOINs`:

```sql
SELECT 
  ts.ID, 
  MAX(ti.Time) AS Time, 
  MAX(ts.TimeStart) AS TimeStart, 
  MAX(tto.Time) AS TimeOut
FROM tableA ts
LEFT JOIN tableB ti ON ts.ID = ti.ID AND ti.Code IN ('IN','IN/OUT') -- "Time IN"
LEFT JOIN tableB tto ON ts.ID = tto.ID AND tto.Code IN ('Out','IN/OUT') -- "Time OUT"
GROUP BY ts.ID
ORDER BY ts.ID
```

Like Impaler mentioned, your description of `IN/OUT` and the desired result you provided don't seem to be in sync.  The example above assumes `IN/OUT` is both `IN` and `OUT`.  This will also give you the max `TimeIn/TimeOut` values if there are duplicate entries.

[DB Fiddle (Postgres)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayA4Zgn3bPZkXZRfZxZJhf/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating table B before the join:

```
WITH cte AS 
 ( -- pivot into in/out time
   SELECT
      ID
     ,Max(CASE WHEN Code IN ('IN', 'IN/OUT') THEN Time END) AS TimeIn
     ,Max(CASE WHEN Code IN ('Out','IN/OUT') THEN Time END) AS TimeOut
   FROM tableB
   GROUP BY ID
 ) 
SELECT
   a.ID
  ,CASE WHEN TimeStart >= TimeIn THEN TimeIn END AS TimeIn
  ,TimeStart                                                                                                                          
  ,CASE WHEN TimeStart <= TimeOut THEN TimeIn END AS TimeIn
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN cte AS b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
```